# grunt.js ember-template-compiler not working

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs

I have the grunt-ember-templates plugin, and it used to work. But I did a `npm install` and it got messed up. Now it does not compile.

The error is this:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "resources\hbs\index\module.hbs" changed.
Running "emberTemplates:compile" (emberTemplates) task
>> ReferenceError: ember-template-compiler.js:22258
>>   module.exports = Ember.__loader.require("ember-template-compiler");
>>   ^
>> module is not defined
Warning: Ember Handlebars failed to compile resources/hbs/error.hbs. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

My Gruntfile.js looks somehow like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        emberTemplates: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    templateBasePath: /resources\/hbs\//,
                    // Path to the ember-template-compiler of my ember version
                    templateCompilerPath: 'resources/js/libs/ember-template-compiler.js',
                    handlebarsPath: 'node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'
                },
                files: {
                    'resources/js/templates.js': 'resources/hbs/**/*.hbs'
                }
            }
        },
...
```

Any idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it was just a dependency problem. Modifying the `package.json` to include the latest packages fixed it.